# Centrar formulario en Bootstrap Input y label

Tags: html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Tengo aquí un formulario, estoy intentando centrar los input y los label. No estoy consiguiendo resultado debido a que aún soy novato en la herramienta.

Este es el codigo del formulario que estoy creando

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Columna derecha-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="box box-warning">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Solicitud de ayuda</h3>
                </div>

                <!--Aqui empieza la informacion del solicitante-->
                <form id="informacionSolicitante" class="user">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Matricula">Matricula:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Nombre">Nombre completo:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Extension">Extension:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="extension" class="form-control form-control-user">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Area">Area:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="area" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Ubicacion">Ubicacion:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="ubicacion" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>




                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Esta es una imagen previa del formulario como se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la versión de Bootstrap 4.3.1, ya he buscado alguna forma de centrar pero solo logro centrar los label necesito centrar con los input tambien Cómo debería hacer para centrar el contenido que tengo en mi formulario

Comment: Con Bootstrap 4 ya hay varias clases útiles para estos casos, si lo requieres puedo postear el código en esa versión, sino sigue la respuesta de @Kamousagi

Comment: Postea tu respuesta la de @Kamousagi no me centro el formulario

Comment: La pregunta inicial indico bootstrap 3, la pregunta cuenta con la etiqueta bootstrap3, por favor cambiala.

Comment: Ya esta actualizada la pregunta con la etiqueta **Bootstrap-4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se modifica la respuesta, en un inicio indicaste usar boostrap 3, se cambia el código con el escenario de boostrap 4.

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <section class="content">
        <div class="row">
            <!--Columna derecha-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
                <div class="box box-warning">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Solicitud de ayuda</h3>
                    </div>

                    <!--Aqui empieza la informacion del solicitante-->
                    <form id="informacionSolicitante" class="user">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Matricula">Matricula:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Nombre">Nombre completo:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Extension">Extension:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="extension" class="form-control form-control-user">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Area">Area:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="area" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Ubicacion">Ubicacion:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="ubicacion" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                            </div>




                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">Cancelar</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Se cambio a **col-sm-6 offset-sm-3**, clases usadas en bootstrap 4.

Puedes obtener mayor información en el siguiente [enlace](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/).

Comment: Amigo no me funciono, quiero ser claro que la version es 4.3.1

Comment: La pregunta inicial indico boostrap 3, se cambio el código bajo boostrap 4, hay otros modos para poder realizar lo requerido, puedes visitar el siguiente enlace: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto con mx-auto.

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <!--Columna derecha-->
        <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="box box-warning">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Solicitud de ayuda</h3>
                </div>

                <!--Aqui empieza la informacion del solicitante-->
                <form id="informacionSolicitante" class="user">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Matricula">Matricula:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="matricula" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Nombre">Nombre completo:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Extension">Extension:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="extension" class="form-control form-control-user">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Area">Area:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="area" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Ubicacion">Ubicacion:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="ubicacion" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                        </div>




                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```